# avoiding adding same key in NSMutableDictionary in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

i add xml data in NSMutableDictionary through element name as key.How can I check
that the key is already available in dictionary when i add the same key again without loop?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
([myDictionary objectForKey:@"my key"] == nil)
```

objectForKey will return nil if a key doesn't exists.

Answer (score 1):

If you ask the dictionary for the object with that key it will return nil if it is not found.

```
if([yourDictionary objectForKey:@"yourKey"] == nil){
  //Do stuff when yourKey is not in the dictionary yet
}
```

Or, if you don't care what happens to the previous value I think you could use

```
[yourDictionary setObject:someObject forKey:someKey]
```

instead of adding objects to the dictionary.